# Specifying the default/root/base environment of conda

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

On my local machine I start a new `conda` environment named after my project. To that end I use the following sample `environment.yml`:

```
name: my-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - jupyter
  - nb_conda
```

In addition, I want to prepare an `docker` image for my project. In particular, I would `COPY` the `environment.yml` in my `Dockerfile` and create the environment. Now it is easy to create the environment in the image. However, the part I fail is to activate `my-env` inside `Dockerfile` and make it the default environment of the image. I tried to include

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate my-env"
```

But when starting a container from the image I get the `base` environment.

Comment: It seems needless. You just need to specify the full path of that env in image such as `/home/user/anaconda/env/my-env/bin/python your_script.py`

Comment: I doubt it. The environment deals not only with the `python` executable, but also with all the packages...

Comment: You can have a try, it will work. BTW, `source activate my-env` also does nothing but inserts the path of `my-env` in front of environment variable `PATH`. It equals to `export PATH=/home/user/anaconda/env/my-env/bin:$PATH`.